# Removing the file extension in a text file bash

Tags: linux, bash

So I have put a load of names of files in a text file, these are specifically `.log` files:

```
ls *.log > finished_data.txt
```

Now that I Have the list of `.log` files, how do I keep the names but remove the `.log` extension? 
My thought process is renaming them all?

Comment: Have you noticed the `Search Q&A` box in the upper right corner of this page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just loop through the `.log` files and move them:

```
for file in *.log
do
    mv "$file" "${file%.log}"
done
```

This uses [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ d="a.log.log"
$ echo "${d%.log}"
a.log
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly how could I reverse the action? say adding the .log on the end to certain files?

Comment: @user3667111 just say `mv "$file" "${file}.log"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf oh thanks, I always get confused with `%` and `%%`. I see `%` strips the shortest match, which is most accurate. Regarding the syntax of the `for` loop: is there any difference?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf ah true! I misunderstood your comment and thought you referred to using `for file in ...; do` instead of `for file in ...` + new line + `do`. You are absolutely right, updating.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rename` to rename all `.log` files by removing `.log` from the end:

```
rename 's/\.log$//' *.log
```

- `\.log$` matches `.log` at the end of the file name and it is being omitted by replacing with blank

If you are using `prename`, then you can do a dry-run first:

```
rename -n 's/\.log$//' *.log
```

If satisfied with the changes to be made:

```
rename 's/\.log$//' *.log
```